# Piping password multiple times to a command via the command line

Tags: bash, sudo, pipe, password

I am running `Ubuntu 18.04` with `bash` and I would like to pass a password to a command that runs with `sudo`, but once its run, i.e the password is piped into the command (a `python3` command to run an `app`), it asks for a passphrase twice, I am trying to do it via this:

`echo "passphrase" | echo "passphrase" | echo $password | sudo command`

but it doesn't seem to be working.

The output from the command is as follows:

```
sudo python3 app.py
Enter PEM pass phrase:
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on https://127.0.0.1:443/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
Enter PEM pass phrase:
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 157-564-730
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2019 18:29:44] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2019 18:29:45] "GET /static/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2019 18:29:45] "GET /static/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2019 18:29:45] "GET /static/css/simple-sidebar.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2019 18:29:45] "GET /static/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2019 18:29:45] "GET /static/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2019 18:29:45] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Does anyone have any ideas how can I go about doing this via a `unix` command inside a bash script?

Comment: I'll edit it, thanks. The command is running a `localhost` app with `sudo`, the password part works, but the passphrase doesn't.

Comment: `echo` is no `cat`; the second `echo` will simply ignore any input from from the first. You could try `{ echo p1; echo p2; echo p3; } | command` or `printf '%s\n' p1 p2 p3 | command`, but there's no telling if command will accept passwords simply from stdin, and not try to open the controlling terminal for that.

Comment: @mosvy Thanks for the answer. It seems like when I run both of those commands, the `p3` is being accepted as my `sudo` password but the others are being ignored.

Comment: Yes, like @mosvy implies, the "localhost app" probably just doesn't accept passwords from stdin. You'll probably have to look up the docs for this program. Sometimes you can read passwords from a file, or embed a command that produces the output, e.g. `python -m keyring get foo bar`.

Comment: The standard way to automatize such things in Unix is with [`expect`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect).

Comment: @mosvy Thanks so much for letting me know about `expect`, it seems like it can do what I want.

Comment: @Sparhawk Thanks for the answer. Its a `python` `flask` app thats asking for the `passphrase` to the key I using to sign the `certificate` for my `TLS` connection, I'll see if there is a possibility of using a file.